# Why are x86 assembler registers named with X H and L?

Tags: assembly, x86, history

I'm learning asm and I'm curious why the names for registers are designated with these letters, as understanding this might help me understand it on another level. I.e. AL is the least significant byte, but what does "L" mean?

Image source: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html

[image: registers]

Comment: `x` - extended, `h` - high byte, `l` - low byte. In the beginning `(a, b, c, d)` - 8-bit processors, and another `byte` for 16-bit processors `(al, ah, bl, bh, ...)`, extended another `word`, e.g.  `(ax, bx, ...)` to 32-bit processors for registers `(eax, ebx, ...)` add another `double-word` 32-bit extension for 64-bit processors `(rax, rbx, ...)` Time marches on...

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question quite clearly

Comment: [Art of Assembly Programming (especially Chaps 1-4)](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~pannain/mc404/aulas/pdfs/Art%20Of%20Intel%20x86%20Assembly.pdf)

Comment: related: [Why are first four x86 GPRs named in such unintuitive order?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5121/why-are-first-four-x86-gprs-named-in-such-unintuitive-order), and [What do the register-names like esi mean, and what special purposes do they have.](http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html).  Of course, when optimizing for performance, not code-size, instructions like `rep scas` aren't always best, so you should pick whatever registers are most convenient (fewest / cheapest instructions) without caring a lot about their names unless the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: By using the similar patterns of register usage may help with compression of code, for example when you are working on 4kB intro, it's sometimes better to use few more `push/pop/mov` instructions to use f.e. `esi` as "source" address everywhere, having like +40B after assembling (than version using spare registers and saving `push/pop` pairs), but less bytes after compression. But this advice is only size-limit-intro coding related, not for "production" SW. And it reads tiny bit better during review, if you use registers in common patterns = advantage even for serious SW (but why asm then?).

Comment: a lot of related and duplicate questions: [Why are x86 registers named the way they are?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/892928/995714), [What does X mean in EAX,EBX...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2545192/995714), [What do the E and R prefixes stand fors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43933379/995714), [x86 register name history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125854/995714)

Comment: Another SO resource is [How to know if a register is a “general purpose register”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45538667/1305969).

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The question as written is an exact duplicate of your 2nd link, because one of the answers there answers the H / L part, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When what began as the "**A**" (*accumulator*) evolved to 16 bits **AX** there was still a need to identify the **L**ow order (7-0) and **H**igh order (15-8) bits. Hence AL & AH. The connotation of low and high had been around for quite awhile, so it's probably for that reason it was adopted, but it could as just as easily been ah = AL = Left 8 bits and al = AR = right 8 bits.

Then when you get into 64 bit, these naming conventions are basically pseudonyms and registers are identified R0 - R15. So **R2B** is CL, **R2W** becomes CX on so on.

Comment: Because of the strange way registers are numbered, CL is R1B and BL is R3B.

Comment: @prl I should have remembered that most documentation does not represent registers in their encoded order. AX = R0W, CX = R1W, DX = R2W, BX = R3W, SP = R4W, BP = R5W, SI = R6W and  DI = R7W. For some reason and even in Intel's documentation it most often AX, BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, SP and BP.