# Putting two numbers into the EAX register

Tags: assembly, nasm, cpu-registers

Im trying to multiply two 16 bit numbers with the following NASM codes:

```
mov ax, [input1]
mov bx, [input2]
mul bx
```

The result of the previous codes is stored in DX:AX

Im trying to print the integer to the screen using a function from a separate library "print_int". But print_int requires that the integer must be in the EAX register.

How can i put the 32-bit integer in the EAX register?

**Update**

I came up with this

```
mov cx, dx  ;move upper half(16 bits) of result in cx
shl ecx, 16 ;shift the contents of ecx 16 bits to the left
mov cx, ax  ;move lower half(16 bits) of result in cx
```

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to put the contents of `DX:AX` into the memory first and then perform `mov eax, [mem32]`

Comment: Sure: `mov [myInt], ax; mov [myInt+2], dx; mov eax, [myInt]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
; Before: 
; Result is in DX:AX on the form ABCD:EFGH
; EAX = ????EFGH : AX contains EFGH, upper part of EAX has unknown content
; EDX = ????ABCD : DX contains ABCD (the 16 most siginficant bits 
;                                   of the multiplication result) 
;                                   like with EAX the upper (=most siginifcant) 
;                                   16 bits of EDX also has unknown content.

and eax, 0x0000ffff ; clear upper bits of eax
; EAX = 0000EFGH

shl edx, 16 ; shift DX into position (will just shift the upper 16 junk bits away)
; EDX = ABCD000

or eax, edx ; combine in eax
; EAX = ABCDEFGH
```

The reason why this works is that `ax` refers to the 16 least significant bits of `eax`. Fore more detail see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228200/x86-assembly-registers-why-do-they-work-the-way-they-do) SO question and the accepted answer. This method will also work for `imul`, but usually you have to be careful when dealing with signed numbers in assembly code.

A complete example:

```
    bits 32

    extern printf
    global main

    section .text
main:
    push ebx
    mov ax, 0x1234
    mov bx, 0x10
    mul bx
    and eax, 0x0000ffff ; clear upper bits of eax
    shl edx, 16 ; shift DX into position
    or eax, edx ; and combine
    push eax
    push format
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    mov eax, 0
    pop ebx
    ret

    section .data
format: db "result = %8.8X",10,0
```

Compile with:

```
nasm -f elf32 -g -o test.o test.asm
gcc -m32 -o test test.o
```

Update:

On 32-bit machines it is usually easier and preferable to deal with 32-bit values if it is reasonable in the context. For example:

```
    movzx eax, word [input1] ; Load 16-bit value and zero-extend into eax
    movzx edx, word [input2] ; Use movsx if you want to work on signed values
    mul eax, edx ; eax *= edx
```

Which also shows the usage of one of the newer, easier to use, `mul` instructions. You can also do as you're doing now and `mov ax, [input1]` and then later extend the size with `movzx eax, ax`.

Comment: `movzx eax,ax` is shorter and better than `and eax, 0x0000ffff`.  Or skip it if you know the upper half of EAX was already zeroed before using a 16-bit `mul`.  But yes, as you say, better to use a 32-bit operand-size multiply in the first place.  (It's `imul eax, edx`, though; Intel chose to use the `imul` mnemonic for the forms that don't produce a high half.  Only the high half is different between `mul` and `imul`.)

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way is...

```
asm
//load test values in eax and exb
        mov     eax,    $00000102
        mov     ebx,    $00000304
//merge ex and bx to eax
        shl     ebx, 16
        shld    eax, ebx, 16
end;
```

result in eax = $01020304

I you want oposite then...

```
asm
//load test values in eax and exb
        mov     eax,    $00000102
        mov     ebx,    $00000304
//merge ex and bx to eax
        shl     eax, 16
        shrd    eax, ebx, 16
end;
```

result in eax = $03040102

Comment: If we're really pushing for the shortest way I propose the following (evil) `66 52 66 50 58` (`push dx; push ax; pop eax`). For reference yours compiles to `C1 E0 10 0F AC D0 10`.

Comment: @user786653: but you need three instructions... :) Push and pop instruction are memory involved instructions and takes much more cpu cycles than only registers involved instructions!

Comment: @user786653: push16/push16 / pop32 is compact, but slow.  Two narrow stores can't forward efficiently to a wider load, so you get a store-forwarding stall, with ~11 cycle latency (vs. 5 cycle latency for normal store/reload) on Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs for example.  http://agner.org/optimize/