# Why does GCC not follow the System V AMD64 ABI here?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [x86 assembly registers — Why do they work the way they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228200/x86-assembly-registers-why-do-they-work-the-way-they-do)

I've compiled the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int square(int x) {
    return x * x;
}

int main() {
    int y = square(9);
    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

two times with different options on OSX with GCC 4.2.1:

`gcc foo.c -o foo_32.s -S -fverbose-asm -m32 -O1`

`gcc foo.c -o foo_64.s -S -fverbose-asm -m64 -O1`

The result for 32 bit:

```
_square:                                ## @square
## BB#0:                                ## %entry
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    imull   %eax, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

And for 64-bit:

```
_square:                                ## @square
Leh_func_begin1:
## BB#0:                                ## %entry
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    imull   %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

As is evident, the 32-bit version retrieves the parameter from the stack, which is what one would expect with cdecl. The 64-bit version however uses the `EDI` register to pass the parameter.

Doesn't this violate the System V AMD64 ABI, which specifies that the `RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9, XMM0–7` registers should be used? Or is this only the case for true 64-bit values like long?

Comment: What's the problem? It should be in `rdi`, it's in `rdi`.. seems about right

Comment: EDI *is* RDI, just half of it in the same way AX is half of EAX

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I thought they were extra registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EDI` is simply the lower half of `RDI` so the compiler is passing the argument in `RDI`, but the argument is only 32-bits long, so it only takes up half of the register.