# Not sure why we add the registers %rdx and %rax when the assembly code has been using %eax and %edx

Tags: assembly, x86

Hello I need some help understanding what is going on in this assembly code:

```
        .file   "mystery.c"

        .text

        .globl mystery

              .type mystery, @function

 mystery:
   pushq    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

   movl %edi, -20(%rbp)
   movl $1, -16(%rbp)
   movl $0, -12(%rbp)
   movl $0, -8(%rbp)
   cmpl $2, -20(%rbp)
   jg   .L2
   movl $1, %eax
   jmp  .L3

  .L2:
movl    $2, -4(%rbp)
jmp .L4

  .L5:
movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
movl    -16(%rbp), %edx
leal    (%rdx,%rax), %eax
movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, -16(%rbp)
addl    $1, -4(%rbp)

.L4:
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
cmpl    -20(%rbp), %eax
jle .L5
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax

.L3:
leave
ret
```

I understand exactly what is going on UNTIL I get to .L5, Here the command `leal(%rdx, %rax)`, eax is what is confusing me.  Up until now ive been moving values to eax and edx and now im adding the values in rdx and rax.  Where is rdx and rax coming from and what values are they holding?  Are they just another way of writing eax and edx?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Assembly question should be tagged with the architeture. [x86]? Something else?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228231/1167234) related answer. It explains the different registers and their evolution. In this case, the `%rax` register is a 64 bit register. `%eax` is the 32 bit one, and `%ax` would be 16 bits. `%ah` refers to the high 8 bits of the 16 bits in the register, and `%al` refers to the lower end.

This little diagram was taken from another answer to the same question, but it shows it well...

```
|63..32|31..16|15-8|7-0|
               |AH.|AL.|
               |AX.....|
       |EAX............|
|RAX...................|
```

Answer (score 8):

Those are "really just" other ways to describe a register. Depending on the "prefix", they're either 64, 32, 16 or 8 bits:

- `rax` - 64 bits
- `eax` - 32 bits
- `ax` - 16 bits
- `ah` - upper 8 bits of `ax`
- `al` - lower 8 bits of `ax`

Answer (score 3):

Because in 64bit mode, `lea` with a 64bit "address" and a 32bit destination is the shortest encoding.

Making it a 32bit address doesn't affect the result, but costs a byte.

Comment: But why not a simple `mov eax, edx`?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc well it adds them, it could have been an `addl %edx, %eax` (aka `add eax, edx`) though.

Comment: yes I know, but why should a lea be used rather than a mov? Will it be faster/shorter

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc there is, as far as I know, no reason to ever use a `lea` if a `mov` could have been used instead. It isn't shorter, and `lea` has slightly lower throughput than `mov` on many µarchs.