# ASSEMBLY: Could someone explain what this line with the leaq instruction does?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

I'm running through some assembly code and I can't figure out what a line of code does.  The code is:

```
 leaq   0(,%rax,4), %rdx
```

I know `lea` is basically a type of `mov` instruction, but it only moves the address.  So we are moving the address of something to `%rdx` (making `%rdx` "point" to something on  the stack).  I know what `%rax` points to on the stack (say, `-28(%rbp)`), but I'm confused by how to multiply that with 4 to get my answer.  Would `%rdx` point to `4*(-28) = -112(%rbp)`?

Thanks!

EDIT:
For context, the following code precedes this instruction:

```
pushq   %rbp 
movq    %rsp, %rbp 
movl    %esi, -28(%rbp)
movl    -28(%rbp), %eax 
cltq 
leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdx
```

Comment: sometime `lea` is also used for calculations. hard to say in your case because you dont give enough code to see.

Comment: Also the 0 on the outside seems unnecessary since it is just going to add nothing to the address. Unless you need it to indirectly access the memory.

Comment: @Fermat2357 I added a summary of the code that precedes the instruction.  Hope that's enough
@emschorsch I agree; I think the `0` is pointless too; it must have been generated by the compiler

Comment: As you can see, whatever is in `%esi` will copied on the stack and then copied to `%eax`. Next `%eax` is extended to 64bit `rax` by the machine command `cltq`. At the end the `leaq` command will multiply `%rax` by 4 and store it into `%rdx`. To be sure for what the hell it is done we need to see what will happen to `%rdx` later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equivalent C code is something like:

```
extern int32 arr[];
int my_func(int32 n, ...) {
   int32 a=n;
   ...
   arr[a];
   ...
}
```

n is passed as a single 32-bit register esi, which is stored to local stack frame.
The parameter is then used in evaluation the 64-bit expression 4*a. The '0' can be explained if it's supposed to be relocated by the linker to the address 'arr'.

Then my guess is that the assembly code is not generated by 
`gcc -S foo.c`, but by `gcc -c foo.c; objdump -d foo.o`

```
   // Similar code from a 32-bit machine
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   6:   8b 04 85 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(,%eax,4),%eax
   d:   5d                      pop    %ebp
   e:   c3                      ret
   f:   90                      nop
```

Comment: You may as well imagine the expression evaluated is &arr[4*n]. (In the disassembly I used arr[4*a], so it uses mov instead of lea.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code is moving whatever is at the address in `%rbp-28` into `%eax`. This will probably be an integer. Then it is just moving that `value*4` into `%rdx` (The 64 bit version of `%eax` similar to the way `%ah` is the high order bytes of `%eax`). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127611/not-sure-why-we-add-the-registers-rdx-and-rax-when-the-assembly-code-has-been) seems to discuss a similar issue.