# GCC-generated asm :: Where did I assign to that register?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, cpu-registers, att

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not sure why we add the registers %rdx and %rax when the assembly code has been using %eax and %edx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127611/not-sure-why-we-add-the-registers-rdx-and-rax-when-the-assembly-code-has-been)

all. 
So, here's my minimal program:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    volatile int a;
    volatile int b;
    volatile int c;
    a = 9;
    b = 15;
    c = a+b;
    return c;
}
```

I now run gcc -S on this, and here's the meat of the generated assembly:

```
.LCFI1:
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)    //unknown setup
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)    //unknown setup
    movl    $9, -4(%rbp)       //a=9, so -4(%rbp) is the register for a.
    movl    $15, -8(%rbp)      //b=15, so -8(%rbp) is b's register.
    movl    -4(%rbp), %edx     //move a into the register for addition.
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax     //move b into the register for additon.
    leal    (%rdx,%rax), %eax  //Add a and b, store in %eax. (PROBLEM LINE)
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)    //Store %eax in c's register.
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax    //get ready to return c. 
    leave                      //we're done here.
    ret
```

Okay, so you see the line I indicate as the problem line. Here's my question: What on earth are %rdx and %rax? The only registers I've loaded things into are %edx and %eax.

Since the program works, %rdx and %rax must be some sort of alias to %edx and %eax, accordingly. Can someone possibly explain the nuances of x86 register nomenclature? I'm completely in the dark on this.

(Of note, if I change the problem line to `addl %edx, %eax`, the result is identical, but if I change it to `addl %rdx, %rax`, I get "Error: Incorrect register '%rax' used with l suffix")

Comment: it's x86_64, not x86. An 64-bit instruction requires the suffix "q", not "l", so you get the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228200/x86-assembly-registers-why-do-they-work-the-way-they-do/228231#228231) if you are unsure about the registers and their sizes. Think of it this way

```
union{
  struct{
    uint32_t eax;
    uint32_t padd;
  };
  uint64_t rax;
};
```

`eax` and `rax` share the same register, `eax` is low part of that register.

This is the reason why `addl` won't work with the registers prefixed with r, they are longer than `addl` is expecting. Try `addq` instead.