# Brackets on registers in Intel x86 assembly syntax

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

I tought I understood brackets in x86 assembly. In this example, the register `ax` should contain `X`, because brackets represents the current address of `LABEL`.

```
mov ax, [LABEL]

LABEL:
db "X", 0
```

But I dont understand the following two assembly lines:

```
mov al, [ebx]
```

Why do I need brackets? Is it because `ebx` is a 32 bits register and `ax` a 16 bits? Whats the difference with:

```
mov al, ebx
```

Or this one, I don't understand why I need brackets...

```
mov [edx], ax
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bracket notation is used to let you access the "value pointed to" by the register or label.

```
mov ax, [LABEL]

LABEL:
db "X", 0
```

You are loading `ax` with the **value** from the memory labeled by `LABEL`. In this case, you are copying the 'X' (0x58 ASCII) into the `ax` register, along with the `0` into the high byte of `ax`.  So `ax = 0x0058`, with `ah = 0`, `al = 0x58`.

`LABEL` is attached to the address where "X" is located.

---

This is not a valid operation:

```
mov al, ebx
```

And this:

```
mov [edx], ax
```

You are moving the value of `ax` into the first two bytes of "the value pointed to by `edx`", since `ax` is a 16 bit register and `edx` is just holding the memory address where it should be written to.

Comment: Note, in some assemblers (actually, most i've seen other than NASM and Yasm), `mov ax, LABEL` actually reads the value at `LABEL`.  In those assemblers, you need something like `mov ax, offset LABEL` or the like to get the value *of* `LABEL`.

Comment: "You are actually setting al with the first byte of the ebx value." vs  "You are setting the first two bytes of the "value appointed by edx" to the value of ax.". You are talking about the first byte and the first two bytes. How do you know the difference? 16 bits vs 32 bits?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228200/x86-assembly-registers-why-do-they-work-the-way-they-do
AX is a 16 bit register, AL is a 8 bit register and EDX is a 32 bit register.

Comment: Yeah, but you said that we are setting the first TWO bytes of the value pointed by edx, to the value of register ax. Is it because ax is a 16 bits (2 bytes) register and so the higher bytes of edx would be set to 0x00?

Comment: You can't actually mov a 32 bit register into a 16 bit register. I'm gonna make a edit to clear this.

Comment: mov al, [ebx] is valid? So we store the value (8 bits) of the address of the 32 bits register in al or we store the value of the content of ebx in the al register? Excuse me, something is not clear for me, with asm pointers..

Comment: mov al, [ebx] is valid, since you are actually saying "copy the value that ebx points to into ax", in this case, 2 bytes will be copied starting at the address appointed to by `ebx`. `mov al, ebx`, though, is not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28691/discussion-between-nathan-and-pier-alexandre-bouchard)

Comment: @cHao What you said is true of MASM/TASM and not of NASM/FASM/YASM.

Answer (score 3):

If we are using the 32 bit register "EDX" as an adressregister using brackets, then the value inside of EDX will be used as an address that points to a ram location. Beginning from this location we can read or write one byte, two bytes, or four bytes.

Examples for writing one byte, two bytes and four bytes:

```
location DB ?, ?, ?, ?
mov edx, offset location
mov eax, 04030201h
```

writing one byte:

```
mov [edx], al
result:
location DB 01, ?, ?, ?
```

writing an other one byte:

```
mov [edx], ah
result:
location DB 02, ?, ?, ?
```

writing two bytes:

```
mov [edx], ax
result:
location DB 01, 02, ?, ?
```

writing four bytes:

```
mov [edx], eax
result:
location DB 01, 02, 03, 04
```

Dirk