# difference between brackets/no brackets nasm/yasm x86_64

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, brackets, yasm

i am learning x86_64 assembly code on yasm and nasm, and i came across with these expressions, and i cant figure out what is happening here, could someone explains me it please?, lets take these snippet as an example:

```
section .data
word db "Hello, Guys!", 0xa
global _start
section .text
_start:
mov rax, word
...
...
...
```

AND

```
section .data
word db "Hello, Guys!", 0xa
global _start
_start:
mov rax, [word]
...
...
...
```

what are the differences between moving the word variable to rax in brackets and without brackets? i already know that the first one is copying the value from word to rax register, and the one with brackets is the effective address

but i cant understand what really is happenning there, i would be grateful if somebody could explains me this, thanks!, i already read some explanations here on stack overflow but none of them answered my question

Comment: No brackets = address, bracket = value from memory. Simple.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This line `mov rax, word` put content of word in rax register,knowing that  word storing address of beginning string "Hello, Guys!"

```
`mov rax, [word]`  put content of address pointed by word
```

Comment: This is a very misleading explanation. `mov rax, word` does not load the content of `word`. Furthermore, where do you get that `word` has the value 0xa?

Comment: what is the content of word after this     `word db "Hello, Guys!", 0xa`

Comment: If you think of `word` as the address of a byte, as I do, then its content is the letter 'H'. If you read it with `mov rax, [word]`, then its content is 0x47202c6f6c6c6548.

Comment: Please see the accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474332/assembly-difference-between-var-and-var

Comment: mov eax,[variable] ; moves content of variable into eax  and

`mov rax, [word]`  put content of address pointed by word , 

[word] it's similar to *pointer and

word it's similar to pointer

Comment: where is stored word ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189026/discussion-between-nissim-abehcera-and-prl).

Comment: `word` isn't "stored" anywhere.  The symbol value (the address) only exists at assemble-time and link time.  If you use it as an immediate or an addressing mode, then it ends up embedded in the machine code after linking.